# Why is there a Math.SQRT2 property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, math.sqrt

Why is there a a property in Javascript that returns the approximate square root of 2. Isn't Math.sqrt(2) enough? There is also a property that returns the square root of 0.5.

I'm wondering out of pure curiosity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a constant used in many math equations. Since it is a constant it doesn't need to be calculated each time it's used, and it has high precision.

Comment: And the same holds for PI, E, LN2, LN10, LOG2E, LOG10E, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Convience factor, as seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2), it is actually a widely used constant.

Answer (score 0):

Some values are used often enough that it's faster to store them as constants than to recompute them. The square roots of 2 and 0.5 are two such constants.